# Verificar se ja existe valor dentro do Array e listview?

Tags: java, android

Como eu posso fazer para que não se repita valores dentro do Array e listview?
Estou fazendo um app, para "cadastro" de codigos.
Tem um EditText, e um botão enviar,  ao clica ele pega esse codigo do EditText e joga para o Listview.

Eu estou usando `if (listaCodigos.contains(codigo))`

Mas não esta funcionando.
Oque estou fazendo errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> listaCodigos = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void alteraLista(View view) {

        EditText campoCodigo = findViewById(R.id.idCodigo);
        String codigo = campoCodigo.getText().toString();

        //Verificando se o campo esta vazio
        if (campoCodigo.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campo Codigo Vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();

            //Verificando se o codigo ja existe
        } else {
            if (listaCodigos.contains(codigo)) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Codigo ja existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

            } else {
                listaCodigos.add("Codigo: " + codigo);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Codigo Adicionado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }

        ListView lista = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaCodigos);
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
        campoCodigo.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No trecho a seguir do seu código, você não adiciona somente a variavel `codigo` à lista, mas sim uma concatenação dela:

```
listaCodigos.add("Codigo: " + codigo);
```

Logo, para sua condição funcionar ela deveria ser:

```
if (listaCodigos.contains("Codigo: " + codigo)) {
```

Comment: Nossa estava na minha cara e eu não consegui ver isso! 
Muito obrigado!
Só precisei colocar o texto entre parentes 
'if (listaCodigos.contains(("Codigo: ") + codigo)) {'